# How can I estimate the influence/significance of the every observation on classification?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, feature-selection, feature-engineering

There are many ways to estimate the significance of the features on the classification model. But how I can estimate the **influence of the every observation on the classification quality**? My thinking is that for every observation the feature significance is not equal, but how to estimate this (if possible)? I use different algorithms for classification: random forest (+GBM) and SVM mainly.

Probably, leave-one-out ? Can you please suggest the reading material on the topic?

Comment: Any answer is going o depend on the classification algorithm, so it may be useful to speak some of what classifiers you are interested in applying.

Comment: I use different algorithms for classification: random forest (+GBM) and SVM mainly (I added this to the question). Closeness to classification plane from SVM?

Comment: In an SVM, only positive $\alpha$ estimates make any contribution to the model predictions. Is this what you're after? Or something else?

Comment: Yes, something in that lines.

Comment: in random forest land we have 'feature contributions' for regression(1) and classification(2).
(1) http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/minf.201000173/full
(2) http://arxiv.org/abs/1312.1121

Comment: Dear Soren, the question is NOT about feature significance, it's about observation significance/influence on the model.

Answer (score 0):

While classical statistics gives you an equation for leverage in a linear model (e.g., the equation given by Agresti (2015), page 59), such an analogue need not exist for the complicated models you are using.

The spirit of the leverage given by the referernce is that any one observation might have a huge influence on the model fit, meaning that dropping that observation would result in dramatically different predictions. A classical linear regression allows you to calculate the leverage using a closed-form solution. I do not expect this to exist for the complicated models you use, especially if you get into tuning hyperparameters using cross-validation like I suspect you do (or at least would be common in much machine learning work). Thus, instead of having an equation to calculate the leverage of each observation, you drop the observation, fit the model on all of the other observations, and check by how much the predictions change. I could see a strategy going something like this.

1. Fit the model to all data and record the predicted values.
2. Drop an observation, and fit the model on the remaining data.
3. Compare the predictions on the smaller model to the predictions by the model. Perhaps calculate the variance, mean absolute deviation, or interquartile range of the changes in predictions, where smaller changes indicate less leverage.
4. Drop another observation and repeat, then another obervation, and so on.
5. If you store the measures of leverage, you can plot a distribution or look at summary statistics to see how influential the particular observations are. If there is a tight cluster, then no individual observation is particularly influential. If some observations result in large changes, you can drill down further and determine which observation is responsible.

(I think this is what you meant by "leave-one-out" and agree with that stance.)

The upside to such an approach is that it is a fairly straightforward coding exercise, rather than a gigantic mess of a mathematical derivation. The downside is that you have to fit a model over and over (oh, the joys of computational statistics).

**REFERENCE**

Agresti, Alan. Foundations of Linear and Generalized Linear Models. John Wiley & Sons, 2015.